# Record phone calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, audio, call-recording

Is there a way to record phone calls? I tried some apps that appeared to work but it seems these only record thru the mic, ideally it should work with headset and earphones too but it doesn't and the sound quality is really poor and buggy. Is there a market leader for this purpose? I want to automatically record all calls and preferably automatically save them to Dropbox, Skydrive or Google Drive. I have Samsung Galaxy S.

### Update

I tried all the phone recording apps and none work.

### Update

Why is something simple so difficult? I tried all the phone recording apps and none work. They don't even look good. This feature lacks support and it is important. We are many users who need to record phone calls. Why can't we?

Comment: This depends on if the kernel has the capability to have the call recording facility activated and enabled in place.

Comment: Link to how I can do it? I don't know how to do it and why is it so difficult to do something simple?

Comment: There's no "how-to-do-it", it is very specific to the manufacturer and kernel, if you're brave enough to hack, mod and recompile kernel, flash it and try it... not all DSP audio chipsets have the feature necessary hence a lot of work involved, not intended for average John Doe user. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Thank you for the information. I've got progress but it's not perfect. I installed a buch of freeware recording to see whether I must do some kernel configuration and it seems that it can record (via microphone(?)) but it might be the case that I must activate some module or so in the kernel since the app I'm recommended in the answer is not working for me. I think this is an important feature that should be included and I see in discussions that I'm not alone in wanted this function. I'm a Java programmer and if I don't find a good 'nuf app I'll strike and make my own app to record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Galaxy Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oduzhar.galaxycallrecorder) yet?

Features list:
- **Recording calls, ability to enable/disable recording service in the settings**
- Showing grouped records extended with contact information such as name and icon.
- Settings to disable recording when headphones on or Bluetooth device connected
- Settings to disable recording for incoming, outgoing call and for some contacts.
- **Ability to specify different audio sources for headphones and Bluetooth devices.**
- Calling, sending SMS, creating an event from the app.
- Ability to stop recording from a notification.
- Ability to play, delete the recent record from a notification.
- Ability to specify a recording delay, a minimal length of records.
- Ability to enable/disable the detailed notifications in the program.
- Ability to record a conversation into a small set of files.
- Deleting a record or many records at once.
- Locking/Unlocking records to prevent unwanted deleting.
- Ability to automatically deleting records.
- **Ability to send records to DropBox, Google Drive, and SkyDrive etc.**
- Integration with Google+.
- Flexible UI settings to change a font size and a background.
- Screen Lock.
- Saving records to MicroSD card, DropBox disk.

If you already tried this, you should mention which apps you tried already.

Answer (score 1):

In some (most) jurisdictions, this is legally not allowed and may fall under wiretapping laws. It would also allow easy covert surveillance by 3rd party apps and would scare most users while only a minority would benefit from it and ise it in the *intended* way.

Think of rogue apps (blackmailing the owner), cheated wifes/husbands wiretapping their SO, the scandal when reporters from the News of the World wiretapped Royals and celebrities, etc.

This is an anti feature that opens a can of worms.

From the technical side:
The Android kernel/API do not expose a way to do that. This is why it doesn't work unless you install a hacked 3rd party firmware that allows that. Searching XDA developers for modded firmware for your model will probably yield some.

Comment: Some phone models allow recording and in many countries recording phone calls is completely legal as long as you are active member of conversation.

Comment: And in the rest of the jurisdictions it's perfectly legal.  The world is not run by a compiler that interprets everything in the worst possible way to prevent you from hanging yourself.  There are plenty of reasons why free people would want to record their own calls, not that free people even need them.